# Where is $\|a\| = \sqrt{\langle a|a\rangle}$ coming from?

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products

I know it is the *norm* of a vector $a$ which generalizes the length (that is what inner products bring from geometric vectors to the rest of vectors) of a vector $a$ in three-dimensional space. What I do not know is why the formula is like that.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried evaluating $\langle a,a\rangle^{1/2}$ when $a$ is two dimensional or three dimensional? That should explain what is going on.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff It seems to me that your argument justifies the definition of the Euclidean norm but not really that of inner product and why they coincide.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I did not evaluate <a,a>^{1/2} What I did not know was the relationship between dot products and inner products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes form the fact that, given two vectors $a$ and $b$, $\langle a|b\rangle=\|a\|\cdot\|b\|\cdot\cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between them. Therefore, if $b=a$, then $\theta=0$ and you get $\langle a|a\rangle=\|a\|^2$.

Comment: Oh I see! So it comes from ⟨a|b⟩=∥a∥.∥b∥.cosθ. So dot product can be considered as a inner product isn't it?

Comment: @JD_PM I dont's understand why you write “can be considered as a inner product”. The dot product in $\mathbb{R}^3$ *is* an inner product.

Comment: Okey, what I meant was if we could consider the dot product ∥a∥.∥b∥.cosθ as an example of inner product

Answer (score 1):

It comes from *Pythagoras' theorem*:

In $\mathbf R^2$ (resp.  $\mathbf R^3$), the usual inner product of vector $u=(x,y)$ and $u'(x',y')$ (resp. $(x,y,z)$ and $(x',y',z')$ is given by
$$\langle u, u'\rangle=xx'+yy',\qquad\langle u, u'\rangle=xx'+yy'+zz'$$
So we see the length of vector $u$, which is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ (resp. $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2)}$ by Pythagoras, can be written as
$$\lVert u\rVert=\sqrt{\langle u,u\rangle}.$$

For other vector spaces on $\mathbf R$, one thus naturally turns the above  property of the *Euclidean inner product* into a *definition* of the norm associated with an inner product, i.e. a *definite positive bilinear form* $\langle \,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,\rangle$ on a vector space $V$.

Similarly, on $\mathbf C^2$, the norm of a vector $(z, u)$ is given by the formula $\lVert(z,u)\rVert = z \bar z+u\bar u$, so for *complex* vector spaces, one defines the norm associated to a *definite positive hermitian form* by the same formula.

Comment: I fully agree that *Pythagoras* is the key word in this question. This is also to some extend the approach described by Axler in his [book](http://linear.axler.net/) (chapter 6).

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the inner product you get taught in school is the *geometric definition* of the *Euclidian inner product* on the *Euclidian vector space* $ℝ^d$, $d=2,3$. 
$$\langle u,v\rangle = |u||v|\cos(ϑ)$$
with $|u|$ being the *magnitude* or *length* of the vector, 
and $ϑ$ the angle between the two vectors. That being accepted as "truth" it follows:
$$\langle u,u\rangle=|u|²\cos(0) = |u|^2.\qquad\qquad (\star)$$

That way of introducing the dot product is fine, because it graphic. And one has an intuitive idea what magnitude and angle means.  You can draw a picture with two vectors and everyone will be able to understand. Additionally that is how math was created using geometrical arguments (think about the old Greeks). Still, I feel uneasy when I am confronted with these kind of definitions. But, it is also possible to define the dot product in a different way, that was introduced later in time:
$$\langle u,v\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^nu_iv_i. $$
This is called the *algebraic definition* of the dot product. [One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Equivalence_of_the_definitions) can show that these definitions are in fact equivalent.

To show the property $(\star)$ for the algebraic definition directly is a bit more complicated. But the interesting part about the dot product is, that it is a special case of a more general object called *inner product*. Of course that will be more abstract, but you will understand better why $(\star)$ holds.

---

**Definition (Inner product):**
Let $F$ denote either the real numbers $ℝ$ or the complex numbers $ℂ$, and let $V$ be a vector space on $F$. Then the mapping $(\cdot,\cdot):V×V→F$ is called *inner product* if it holds:

1. Linearity: $(αx_1+βx_2,y) = α(x_1,y)+β(x_2,y),\text{ for } α,β∈F$.
2. Symmetry: $(x,y)=\overline{(y,x)}$.
3. Definiteness: $(x,x)∈ℝ;\ (x,x)\geqslant0;\ (x,x)=0\ ⇒\ x=0$.

**Definition (Norm):** Let $V$ be again a vector space on $F$. Then a mapping $\|\cdot\|:V→ℝ$ is called *norm* (on $V$) if it holds:

1. Definiteness: $\|x\|\geqslant0;\ \|x\|=0\ ⇔\ x=0$.
2. Homogeneity: $\|αx\|=|α|\|x\|,\ α∈F$.
3. Triangle Inequality: $\|x+y\|\leqslant\|x\|+\|y\|$.

---

Now the cool thing about these two definitions is their connection: 
**Theorem:** An inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)$ of a vector space $V$ on $F$ induces a norm by $$\|x\|:=(x,x)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$
**Proof:** We have to prove all three properties of the norm. Definiteness and homogeneity of the norm directly follows from the definiteness and linearity of the inner product. To show the triangle inequality it is:
\begin{align*}
\|x+y\|^2 &= (x+y,x+y) = (x,x)+(x,y)+(y,x)+(y,y) \\
&\leqslant\|x\|^2+2|(x,y)|+\|y\|^2 \leqslant¹\|x\|^2+2\|x\|\|y\|+\|y\|^2=(\|x\|+\|y\|)^2.
\end{align*}
We used the [Cauchy-Schwarz-inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality):
$$|(x,y)|^2\leqslant(x,x)(y,y),$$
in $\leqslant¹$.

---

Now back to the question. These two definitions and the theorem gives us cool tools that can be applied on the *dot product* $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ on $ℝ^n$.
One can show that the *dot product* is in fact an inner product. Hence, using the theorem, the following expression
$$ \|u\|_2:=\sqrt{(u,u)}= \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^nu_i^2}$$
is a *norm* on $ℝ^n$.